# Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection

Tags: vb.net

Tengo el siguiente ejecicio: debo ingresar coordenadas(x,y), son pares, es decir x1,y1,x2,y2. Necesito estos pares para poder realizar el calculo correctamente.
Cuento si la cantidad de coordenadas para ambos casos son menores que 2, en ese caso, el calculo no podrá realizarse, de lo contrario, si se realizara.
Tengo el error del titulo, específicamente cuando agrego el calculo al arraylist "Distancias".

```
**Sub Main(args As String())

        Dim x, y As Byte

        Dim opcion As Byte

        Dim CoordenadasX As ArrayList = New ArrayList()

        Dim CoordenadasY As ArrayList = New ArrayList()

        Dim Distancias As ArrayList = New ArrayList()

        Do

            IngresarCoordenadas(x, y)

            CoordenadasX.Add(x)

            CoordenadasY.Add(y)

            Console.WriteLine("Desea ingresar otra coordenada? 0 para salir, 2 para continuar. ")

            opcion = Console.ReadLine()

            If opcion = 0 Then

                Exit Do

            Else

                Console.WriteLine("Ok continuemos...")

            End If

        Loop While opcion <> 0

        CalculoDistancia(CoordenadasX, CoordenadasY, Distancias)

        For Each coordenadas As Double In Distancias

            Console.WriteLine(coordenadas)

        Next

        Distancias.Sort()

        Console.WriteLine("La menor distancia es: {0}", Distancias(0))

        Console.WriteLine("La mayor distancia es: {0}", Distancias((Distancias.Count - 1)))


    End Sub

    Sub IngresarCoordenadas(ByRef x As Byte, ByRef y As Byte)

        Do

            Console.WriteLine("Ingresar coordenada x: ")

            x = Console.ReadLine()

            Console.WriteLine("Ingresar coordenada y: ")

            y = Console.ReadLine()

        Loop Until ValidarCoordenadas(x, y)

    End Sub


    Function ValidarCoordenadas(ByRef x As Byte, ByRef y As Byte) As Boolean

        If x > 0 AndAlso y > 0 AndAlso x <= 200 AndAlso y <= 200 Then

            Return True

        Else

            Console.WriteLine("Valor invalido!")

        End If

        Return False

    End Function


    Sub CalculoDistancia(ByRef CoordenadasX As ArrayList, ByRef CoordenadasY As ArrayList, ByRef Distancias As ArrayList)

        If (CoordenadasX.Count < 2) OrElse (CoordenadasY.Count < 2) Then

            Console.WriteLine("La cantidad de coordenadas es insuficiente para realizar el calculo!")

        Else

            Dim i = 0

            Do While (i < CoordenadasX.Count)

                Dim j = CoordenadasX.Count + 1

                Do While (j > i)

                    Distancias.Add(Math.Sqrt((Math.Pow((CType(CoordenadasX(i), Integer) - CType(CoordenadasX(j), Integer)), 2) + Math.Pow((CType(CoordenadasY(i), Integer) - CType(CoordenadasY(j), Integer)), 2)))) ''Linea del error (Index was out of range...)

                    j = j - 1

                Loop

                i = (i + 1)

            Loop

        End If




    End Sub**
```

Comment: Dim j = CoordenadasX.Count + 1
 si escribis eso, y despues haces CoordenadasX(j) entonces es un item que no existe... queda claro?